# Substituting redundant subsets

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, data-structures

I have given a set of sets of tuples with two elements (they are ordered by the second element):

```
{
{(1,"c1"), (1,"c2"), (1,"c3"), (1,"c5")}
{(1,"c1"), (2,"c3"), (1,"c5")},
{(1,"c1"), (1,"c3"), (1,"c5")},
}
```

The Task is substitute redundant subsets of elements. Given a number k >= 1. Replace all subsets with at least k elements, which appear more than once in the sample set. The substitution sequences should be as big as possible.
The reduced form:

```
{
{z, (1,"c2")}
{(1,"c1"), (2,"c3"), (1,"c5")},
{z},
}
z := {(1,"c1"), (1,"c3"), (1,"c5")}
```

My native approach would be,
start with set one, and then for each set calculate how many matches they have. Then choose the one with the biggest matches and substitute. Then restart this process until no other set has more than k matches. Then move to the next set and do the same thing, where you can neglect all previous sets.

The elements are only equal if both values match. The second value is a string, but it might be performance vice better to replace them first with a number. The first one is a floating point number.

This looks for me much like data compression. Is there a more efficient algorithm to calculate this? Is there a good data structure for this purpose?

Comment: Is there a typo in the second line of your second snippet? Should it read: `{z, (1,"c2")}` ? Also, this seems to resemble a [longest repeated sub-sequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem).

Comment: yes fixed it, yeah that looks like what i was looking for

Comment: The technique you described, you need to pick every possible sequence from one set and compare it with every other set. That seems O(n!xm) time complexity. where n is average set size and m is number of sets. That can get out of hand very very quickly. Your problem is slightly more complicated than the wiki problem in that your substring need not be contiguous to be a match (like the extra c2 in line2 is still a match). If you can still beat this problem into that shape somehow, O(nxm) would be a big improvement.

Comment: Just saw your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996166/matching-number-string-pairs This question seems to be a sequel to that one, as in, it is using the output that regex spits out? Just to ensure we're not chasing an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you maybe describe what you're actually trying to do with these manipulations?

Comment: The file consists of linear equations. After i read in all equations, i need to detect redundant parts which appear in many equations and insert them as a new equation setting them equal to a substitution variable, which then gets inserted into the original positions. The system will get bigger, but more sparse since every row contains fewer entries.

Comment: In that case, why is `(2,c3)` not equal to `(1,c3) (1,c3)` in the third line of your second snippet? Shouldn't the 3rd line reduce to `z, (1,c3)` ?

Comment: There a multiple reduction possible, {(1,"c1"), (1,"c5")} := z could be replaced 3 times, but z := {(1,"c1"), (1,"c3"), (1,"c5")} is longer and this way more desirable, because it is longer, even if it could only replace 2 equations parts. (2,c3) appears only once, so it can never be part of a substitution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76741/discussion-between-rage-and-quesaionasis).

Answer (score 0):

If the number of variables in your linear equations are lesser than the number of equations, you can figure out the largest substitution faster with this alternate method:

#### Problem Statement

We've clarified in the comments that `z := (1,"c3")` *can* partially substitute `{2,"c3"}` as `{z,(1,"c3")` Given this, the fact that the data points are tuples is irrelevant as far as this question is concerned - allowing me to treat your input as:

```
  {c1, c2, c3, c5}
  {c1, c3, c5}
  {c1, c3, c5}
```

The problem is then to find the largest set {ca,cb..} that is a subset of atleast 2 input sets.

The input sets can be expressed as

```
     | c1 | c2 | c3 | c5 |
+----|----|----|----|----|
| S1 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
| S2 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  |
| S3 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  |
```

#### Solution

The solution A will be of the form

```
     | c1 | c2 | c3 | c5 | subset of |
+----|----|----|----|----|-----------|
| A  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | k         |
```

Where k is the number of input sets A belongs to, and needs to be greater than 2. Now for n values of cx, A has take 2^n possibilities. Evaluating if candidate solution Ax is a subset of set Sx, involves bitwise AND of bitfield Ax with bitfield Sx, and then ANDing the individual bits of the result.

Iterating through possible values for Ax, starting with most bits set, the first value of A with k>1 is the required solution.

```
| s  | c1 | c2 | c3 | c5 | subset of |
|----|----|----|----|----|-----------|
| A1 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1         |
| A2 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0         |
| A3 | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0         |
| A4 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 3 <-bingo!|
| A5 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  |           |
| A6 | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |           |
| A7 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |           |
| A  ...                             |
```

#### Complexity

The time complexity of this solution is still exponential. However, it is exponentially dependent on the number of values of cx. As opposed to the naïve solution which is exponential on the number of input sets. If the number variables (cx) is smaller than the number of input sets (Sx), this method will be faster.

**Note:** If the assumption at the top of this solution about `(2,"c3")` is incorrect, then you just have to treat `(2,"c3")` as a separate cx value. The input becomes:

```
{c1, c2, c3, c5}
{c1, c6, c5}
{c1, c3, c5}
```

and the rest of this answer remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maps` for this purpose

consider `set of sets of tuples` as a `set of maps` , now the problem becomes whether the `'z' map` is subset of `each map` ,if subset , we need to output the `map 'z'` as z and rest of the elements of map as `pairs` ,if not , we need to simply output the `map`

Now, to find if it a `map is subset of another map` , we use `STL` function:

[Includes](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/includes.html)

> Includes tests whether one sorted range includes another sorted range. That is, it returns true if and only if, for every element in [first2, last2), an equivalent element [1] is also present in [first1, last1) [2]. Both [first1, last1) and [first2, last2) must be sorted in ascending order.
>
> The two versions of includes differ in how they define whether one element is less than another. The first version compares objects using operator<, and the second compares objects using the function object comp.

here is the program which prints if `map is subset`, modify it with ur requirements and u can try the output program by ur own(`as it is easy one`) :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> a,b;
    

    a[0] = "0";
    a[1] = "1";
    b[0] = "0";

    std::cout << "b ⊆ a? " << std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()) << " (will be 1)\n";

    b[1] = "1";
    std::cout << "b ⊆ a? " << std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()) << " (will be 1)\n";

    b[2] = "2";
    std::cout << "b ⊆ a? " << std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()) << " (will be 0)\n";
}
```