# Matching number string pairs

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following sample string:

```
 R10666: 273141 C1 + 273141 C2 + 273141 C3 + 273141 C4 + 273141 C5 - 273141 C6
```

I want to obtain:

```
[('273141','C1'), ..., ('- 273141', 'C6')]
```

The numbers can be floating point numbers with exponential notation i.e. `- 2.5e-7`.

My current regex looks like this:

```
re.findall(r'([+-]? \d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?)( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', split)
```

But it doesn't produce the correct output, what is wrong with it?

This is a sample output:

```
(' 273141', '', '', ' C1')
```

or it matches nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted the [Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) regex for you and shortened the regex a bit (note the alternative list is gone that means less backtracking, and the `(?i)` case insensitive matching option in front to turn `[A-Za-z]` into `[a-z]`):

```
import re
s = "R10666: 273141 C1 + 273141 C2 + 273141 C3 + 273141 C4 + 273141 C5 - 273141 C6"
print re.findall(r'(?i)([-+]?\s*\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)(\s+\w+)', s)
```

Output of the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/QzK9NM):

```
[(' 273141', ' C1'), ('+ 273141', ' C2'), ('+ 273141', ' C3'), ('+ 273141', ' C4'), ('+ 273141', ' C5'), ('- 273141', ' C6')]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will put all the submatches in the results. In your case, the empty strings come from the unmatched decimals if they are present; so use non-capture groups instead:

```
([+-]? \d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?) ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

I also moved the space at the second capture group outside so you don't get that leading space.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB7xL2/1)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/duZJJO)

Comment: It doesn't match for example 2.263574e+07

Comment: @quesaionasis Please update your question as such. I really want to help you, but if the question is not complete, I cannot do more than that. Going beyond what you ask will involve making assumptions, and so doing can introduce wrongs thus be not what you expect.